# Leaning Porch Fix or Replace?

Tags: wood, carpentry, porch

Just purchased this house and need to correct the porch per city inspection. House was built in the early 1900s, and has seen severe foundation issues. The foundation has been fixed and jacked up, but the porch is still wonky. It's very solid and doesn't move at all, but is leaning away from the house and to the right. What can I do to get it upright? Or is it less expensive just to rebuild it? My budget is has been eaten by the foundation, roof and plumbing.

I have uploaded pictures below and also to Imgur here: https://imgur.com/a/snbPxQH

[image]

[image]

Comment: There should be about 1/8" per foot slope on the deck surface in the direction of the second picture arrows for drainage.

Comment: does your ground freeze?   wood touching soil is no good.  what is frost depth?

Answer (score 3):

A typical correction attempt for the rightwards lean would be a galvanized steel tie-rod with a turnbuckle in the middle to tighten it running from the top of the right post (the square black ones under the porch deck level) to the bottom of the left post to pull both posts back into plumb. The porch deck framing will push the top of the left post as the tie rod pulls on the top of the right post.

If the posts are sunk deep in the ground you may have to dig them out to correct it as a tie rod above ground may not have enough leverage to move the posts against the soil.

Since there don't appear to be posts on the house side you'd have to anchor any similar tie rod in that direction low on the foundation and high on the post.

You'll also need to check if the above deck taller posts will end up plumb with the deck pulled into place. They eyball as straighter than the below deck posts now, so they might end up out of whack more after straigtening the bottom, and might need to be relocated to correct that - which might be a push towards rebuilding it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, @Ecnerwal. I'm currently looking at braces, turnbuckles etc. I see the style you're describing is available as a screen door brace, but I'm not sure if that's strong enough. Should I be looking at fence/gate braces?
Like this one: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-Telescoping-Gate-Brace-60250/319803099?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US

Comment: That seems a bit light-duty. You'll need a heavy one. Anonther possibility is just to use threaded rod, or rod with threaded ends, and large washers/nuts (drilling right through the posts to install the rod) then just tighten down the nuts at the ends. The turnbuckle is elegant, and the usual solution, but not really *essential* to doing the job, here. A rod you can make shorter that will take considerable force is what's needed.